# How to get string as user input in objective c (using the terminal as input)?

Tags: objective-c, macos, terminal

I'm just creating a simple program that gets user input then prints it back in the terminal. I don't know how to get the user input as an NSString. I've read about scanf() in C but that doesn't seem to be able to take strings. I was wondering if there is a possible way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
printf("Enter your string: ");
scanf("%s", str);                    // read and format into the str buffer
printf("Your string is %s\n", str);    // print buffer

// you can create an NS foundation NSString object from the str buffer
NSString *lastName = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:str];

// %@ calls description o object - in NSString case, prints the string
NSLog(@"lastName=%@", lastName);
```

Comment: Personally wouldn't recommend using scanf for buffer reasons in situations where user types excessive characters.

Answer (score 0):

```
       scanf("%s",str);
       mystr = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:str];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the C library function `scanf` to read a C string from the standard input, and then create an `NSString` from that with `initWithCString:encoding:`.

Comment: I had a look at the that method but didn't know what to put in the encoding: bit?

Comment: Use `NSUTF8StringEncoding` for the typical cases. Have a look a the documentation about [Creating strings](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/CreatingStrings.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use one of the following two string functions:

```
 #include <stdio.h>

 char *fgets(char * restrict str, int size, FILE * restrict stream);

 char *gets(char *str);
```

Using `gets` is simpler, but it's unsafe for use in production code. Here's an example using `fgets`:

```
#define MAX_LENGTH 80

- (void)example
{
    char buf[MAX_LENGTH];
    fgets(buf, MAX_LENGTH, stdin);

    NSString *s = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:buf];
    NSLog(@"%@", s);
}
```